# SQL_MODE="" but still getting ER: 1055 Group By Required

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver, mysql-error-1055

SPECS: Windows 10 running WAMP, MySQL v 5.7.14

So this lovely error is causing a great deal of head scratching:

> 14:28:30CALL storedemo.usp_GenerateAprioriRules(0.05, 50) Error Code: 1055. Expression#1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and containsnonaggregated column 'storedemo.tbltotalorder.itemName' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by 0.109 sec

I have followed every thread here and set SQL_MODE="", however I am still receiving this error. I even used the built in option under MySQL tools via Wampserver to set it to null.

Running each of these gives me empty values:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

Yet, it seems mysql is still enforcing this rule. Not exactly sure how to proceed with this. Attached is my ini file, which shows the option is set to null - yet this error remains.

```
; Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
;
; This is for a large system with memory of 1G-2G where the system runs mainly
; MySQL.
;
; MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
; locations which depend on the deployment platform.
; You can copy this option file to one of those
; locations. For information about these locations, see:
; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
;
; In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
; If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
; with the "--help" option.

; The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
;password = your_password
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

; Here follows entries for some specific programs

; The MySQL server
[wampmysqld64]
;skip-grant-tables
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 16M

;Added to reduce memory used (minimum is 400)
table_definition_cache = 600

sort_buffer_size = 2M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
;Path to mysql install directory
basedir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14"
log-error="c:/wamp64/logs/mysql.log"
;Verbosity Value  1 Errors only, 2  Errors and warnings , 3 Errors, warnings, and notes
log_error_verbosity=2
;Path to data directory
datadir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/data"

;Path to the language
;See Documentation:
; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-language.html
lc-messages-dir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/share"
lc-messages=en_US

; The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
; New for MySQL 5.6 default_tmp_storage_engine if skip-innodb enable
; default_tmp_storage_engine=MYISAM

;To avoid warning messages
secure_file_priv="c:/wamp64/tmp"
skip-ssl

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=true

; The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes:
; ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.
; no line sql-mode="" gives default SQL mode
; To clear the SQL mode explicitly, set it to an empty string using sql-mode=""
sql-mode=""
;sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"


; Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
; if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
; All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
; Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
; (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
;
;skip-networking

; Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

; Replication Master Server (default)
; binary logging is required for replication
;log-bin=mysql-bin

; binary logging format - mixed recommended
;binlog_format=mixed

; required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
; defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
; but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id = 1

; Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)

; New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start

;
; To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
; two methods :
;
; 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
;    the syntax is:
;
;    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
;    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
;
;    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
;    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
;
;    Example:
;
;    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
;    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
;
; OR
;
; 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
;    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
;    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
;    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
;    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
;    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
;    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
;    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
;    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
;
; required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
; (and different from the master)
; defaults to 2 if master-host is set
; but will not function as a slave if omitted
;server-id       = 2
;
; The replication master for this slave - required
;master-host     =   <hostname>
;
; The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
; to the master - required
;master-user     =   <username>
;
; The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
; the master - required
;master-password =   <password>
;
; The port the master is listening on.
; optional - defaults to 3306
;master-port     =  <port>
;
; binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
;log-bin=mysql-bin

; Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
;tmpdir   = /tmp/
;log-update   = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

; The InnoDB tablespace encryption feature relies on the keyring_file
; plugin for encryption key management, and the keyring_file plugin
; must be loaded prior to storage engine initialization to facilitate
; InnoDB recovery for encrypted tables. If you do not want to load the
; keyring_file plugin at server startup, specify an empty string.
early-plugin-load=""

; Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
;innodb_data_home_dir = C:/mysql/data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
;innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:/mysql/data/
;innodb_log_arch_dir = C:/mysql/data/
; You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
; of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
; Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 60
innodb_flush_method=normal

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
; Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
;safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port = 3306
```

Comment: I guess something is changing the sql mode (at least for the session that is running the procedure), or maybe you are testing a different server. I would try to set (or check) the mode to "" directly inside that procedure, and if that works, trying to debug your path back to figure out where the mode is set.

Comment: Or, of course, you could just fix your query to use `GROUP BY` properly :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out two things: 1) That after going crazy trying to figure out why it wasnt taking - the obvious became obvious - I had to close MySQL workbench while making the changes in WAMP. Then, commit them, and restart the service. It seems that having both running was conflicting with one another. 2) I had to drop and recreate the Stored Procedures afterward - then everything was fine. It seems to be a Win 10 issue, because in Windows 7 I just made the changes in Workbench and it took. I have it set to: 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'

Answer (score 2):

Are you executing a User Function? this store the sql_mode applicable when the function was created.

If you put sql_mode to blank and re-save o re-create the function, will get the new sql_mode values.

Tested in Mysql 5.7

Comment: Yes it was a stored procedure. I figured out two things: 1) That after going crazy trying to figure out why it wasnt taking - the obvious became obvious - I had to close MySQL workbench while making the changes in WAMP. Then, commit them, and restart the service. It seems that having both running was conflicting with one another. 2) I had to drop and recreate the Stored Procedures afterward.

Comment: In my case, I modify the function adding anithing that make no conflict with this, and then save it. Be Sure that you don't have only_full_group_by in sql_mode. It will be saved with the sql_mode are you using at this moment.